# In MS Access - How do I use a macro to change the caption of a label so that it matches the caption of a text box in a report?

Tags: ms-access

The label that I'd like to change the caption of has the name: "lblEventNameLabel"
The text box that holds the value that I want to update the label has the name "txtEventNameLabel"
The name of the report is "rptBookingConfirmation"

I've got as far as creating this Macro in the "On Load" part of the report:

SetProperty

Control Name lblEventNameLabel

Property Caption

Value [txtEventNameLabel]

When I open the report it updates the caption to "[txtEventNameLabel" instead of the value that is in the text box. I've also tried chaning the Value in SetProperty to [rptBookingConfirmation]![txtEventNameLabel] and [Reports]![rptBookingConfirmation]![txtEventNameLabel] but those have the same result.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.lblEventNameLabel.Caption = "Your Text"
```

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.